# What is the difference between $[H, g]$ and $[h, g]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, notation

I am working on this problem, where $[H, g]$ is the commutator group:

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, show that $[H, g] = [H, \langle g \rangle]$.

Before solving it, I need to understand the difference between $[H, g]$ and $[h, g]$ because the writer of this problem used $[H, g]$ not without a purpose. Therefore here is my question:

> What is the difference between the set builders of $[H, g]$ and $[h, g]$ in term of solving this problem?

Thank you for your time.

**POST SCRIPT : ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~** 

I use the set builder given by *@nullUser* but am still stuck one step short:

$$\begin{align}
[H,g] :&= \{[h,g] : h \in H \} = \{hgh^{-1}g^{-1} : h \in H \}\\
&= \{hg(g^{n-1})(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} : h \in H \} \\
&= \{h(gg^{n-1})(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}g^{-1} : h \in H \} \\
&= \{hg^n\underbrace{(g^{n-1})^{-1}h^{-1}}_{\text{non-commutative!}}g^{-1} : h \in H \} \\
\end{align}$$

If only the elements are commutative then I am done. This was the reason behind my posting: Perhaps I have been so carried away by the usual set builder of $[h, g]$ that I missed something from $[H, g]$. Any other ideas of proving it?

Comment: Even if $[H,g]$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by all commutators $[h,g]$ with $h \in H$, I am not convinced that this is correct. Where does the problem come from?

Comment: @DerekHolt : It comes from my class note on Group Theory. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$[H,g]$ denotes the set of all commutators of the form $[h,g]$ with $h \in H$

Comment: Is there any way to write down in set builder? Thanks.

Comment: @A.Magnus: $\{g \in G: g=[h,g_1], \text{ for some $h \in H$}\}$

Answer (score 1):

Since you want set builder notation:

$$
[H,g] := \langle\{[h,g] : h \in H \}\rangle = \langle\{hgh^{-1}g^{-1} : h \in H \}\rangle
$$

where here the angled brackets indicate that we need to take the subgroup generated by elements of this form. (Thanks to comments for pointing this out.)

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't mean the subgroup generated by $[h,g]$? It is not at all clear that the set you defined is a subgroup .

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right, this fails for free groups. The set defined in this answer is set of generators, not the group itself.

Comment: @nullUser : See the Post Script above. Thanks!